# sign XML with public Key

Tags: c#, xml, public-key-encryption, xml-signature

I am rather new to .Net MVC and even newer to Signatures.

I have to sign a XML file anveloped and then send it to my client with a response stream.

Aftwe a whole bunch of fights with the code i was be able to sign my XML Enveloped. 
With the RSACryptoServiceProvider Private Key, Dataobject, KeyInfo and everything.

But then my Client told me i only get a public key from him.

After a day of searching through the internet i still dont know how.

So my question:
How can I sign my XML with a public key in .Net MVC with C#?

Comment: You don't sign with a public key.  That's what the private key is for.

Comment: However, the word "enveloped" probably means you have to encrypt it as well (usually you sign first and then encrypt, but you can do it the other way around too, if the receiver only accepts your messages). Encryption is performed using their public key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot sign an XML file with a public key, public keys are only for validation.

For signing you will need a private key, this key can be generated by OpenSSL. You can work on this for the moment and then you should ask to your client to merge your code with his keystore implementation.

Once you are able to sign your file, you'll see the certificate in base64 format as part of the signed document, this certificate includes a public key which is used to validate the sign done by the private key.

Comment: Thank you :) i did just that about a month ago. Client doesnt really get it though...